# Pytorch Convolutional Autoencoder output is blurry. How to improve it?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder

I created Convolutional Autoencoder using Pytorch and I'm trying to improve it.

For the encoding layer I use first 4 layers of pre-trained `ResNet 18 model` from `torchvision.models.resnet`.

I have mid-layer with just one `Convolutional layer` with input and output channel sizes of 512. For the decoding layer I use `Convolutional layers` following with `BatchNorm` and `ReLU` activation function.

The decoding layer reduces the channel each layer: `512 -> 256 -> 128 -> 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 3` and increases the resolution of the image with interpolation to match the dimension of the corresponding layer in the encoding part. For the last layer I use `sigmoid` instead of `ReLu`.

All `Convolutional layer`s are:

```
self.up = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(input_channels, output_channels, 
                    kernel_size=5, stride=1,
                    padding=2, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(output_channels),
                nn.ReLU()
            )
```

The input images are scaled to `[0, 1]` range and have shapes `224x224x3`. Sample outputs are (First is from training set, the second from the test set):

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erk6z.png)

[First image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLl67.png)

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4yWH.png)

[Second image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiM7e.png)

Any ideas why output is blurry? The provided model has been trained around `160 epochs` with `~16000` images using `Adam` optimizer with `lr=0.00005`.  I'm thinking about adding one more `Convolutional` layer in `self.up` given above. This will increase complexity of the model, but I'm not sure if it is the right way to improve the model.

Comment: Shouldn't your decoding layers have `ConvTranspose2d`? Also, ResNets have a 7 by 7 convolutional layer and a Maxpool layer at the start. So, have you considered those while decoding (to maintain symmetry, though it's not compulsory)? Also, you can try to increase the learning rate a bit (maybe 1e-4 or 5e-4).

Comment: Autoencoders are pretty much always blurry. Isn't this the motivation for why GANs were developed?

Comment: @akshayk07 thanks for your response. I used `ConvTranspose2d` before for other tasks, but I found out that usually `Conv2d` followed by `nn.functional.interpolate` works better. I will try to change such that I maintain symmetry. I used 1e-3 and 1e-4 but I saw that the loss bounced too much, so I used smaller learning rate.

@jodag thanks for your response. I tried to view outputs of other autoenoders and they were blurry too. I think I cannot improve the output much.

Comment: I guess question is what are you trying to achieve with this Autoencoder? Are you trying to project your data to lower dimension and then use that for classification, regression, etc? It might not matter if your reproductions are blurry.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an L2 or MSE loss on the pixel values. As of 2016, SOTA is to use perceptive losses - a fancy way of using the feature extractor of a CNN (just remove the final classification head) and use the L2/MSE error of the features.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08155